# problema con ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, server, redes

al hacer comando con **ip a**, me sale una tarjeta de red que no conozco, la docker0, estoy configurando un dominio, pero me esta dando fallas, supongo que es por esa red, adjunto captura[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y adjunto captura del comando nslookup
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]